# resizing of grid when resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I used a [fill whole window](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example12-fillbrowser.html) example as a default.
Tried to resize browser window: but area, that is used for grid is the same. Need to reload page so that it fits. 
How can I archive this without reloading page ?

**Edited**

Interesting fact that when I change order of columns grid is resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did this way :

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#grid").height($("<container for grid>").height());
$(".slick-viewport").height($("#grid").height());
});
```

Thanks to jQuery and its height() function

Comment: this may cause content not updating when scrolling in bottom limit.

Comment: -1: Use the API.  Don't just change the size of one element. There may be unknown consequences.

Answer (score 12):

This works fine for me. Maybe the `resizeCanvas()` function is a new feature in slick grid.

The code is CoffeeScript.

```
$(window).resize -> grid.resizeCanvas()
```

Answer (score 5):

This works better than just changing .slick-viewport height.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var h=$(window).height();
    $('#myGrid').css({'height':(h-65)+'px'});
    grid.resizeCanvas();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work just fine:

```
$( window ).resize( function() {
    grid.resizeCanvas();
});
```