# Slickgrid: Final column autosize to use all remaining space

Tags: slickgrid, autosize, tablecolumn

I'm using SlickGrid and struggling to find an elegant solution to the following:

1. All columns must have a specific initial width when first rendered but be resizable afterwards
2. The final column should auto fill the remaining column space when the window is resized

I've seen:

[Make one column fill remaining space in SlickGrid without messing up explicit width columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880485/make-one-column-fill-remaining-space-in-slickgrid-without-messing-up-explicit-wi)

[resizing of grid when resizing browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084408/resizing-of-grid-when-resizing-browser-window)

[How do I autosize the column in SlickGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794656/how-do-i-autosize-the-column-in-slickgrid)

But these don't seem to quite do what I need. 
If I use the forceFitColumns option, then all columns will autosize (unless I put a maxsize on them).
Using resizeCanvas on window.resize works well - but it still only works if forceFitColumns is true.

If I set `minWidth=maxWidth` - then I can't resize the column.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure it would correct all your problem but in my case I do use the `forceFitColumns` and then depending how I want my column to react in size I will use a combination of `minWidth` and `width`, and in some cases the ones that will never exceed a certain width, I would then use a `maxWidth` as well. Now the problem you have is when setting the `minWidth` to be the same with as `maxWidth` this of course will make it unresizable, well think about it you set a minimum and a maximum, SlickGrid is respecting it by now being able to size it afterwards. I also have my grid which takes 95% width of my screen so I have a little padding on the side and with it I use a auto-resize using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
// HTML Grid Container
<div id="myGridContainer" style="width:95%;">
    <div class="grid-header" style="width:100%">
        <label>ECO: Log / Slickgrid</label>
        <span style="float:right" class="ui-icon ui-icon-search" title="Toggle search panel" onclick="toggleFilterRow1()"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></div>
    <div id="myPager"></div>
</div>

// My SlickGrid Options
var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    forceFitColumns: true
};

// The browser auto-resize 
$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#myGrid").width($("myGridContainer").width());
    $(".slick-viewport").width($("#myGrid").width());
    grid.resizeCanvas();
});
```

**EDIT**
I also was annoyed by the fact that using all of these together is blocking you from resizing the width of the column. I came up with a different solution, much later after, which makes the fields to expand (take available width) and does not block you afterwards on resizing the width. So this new solution I believe is giving you exactly what you are looking for... First of all remove the `maxWidth` property and only use `minWidth` and `width`, actually you could probably use only the `width` if you wanted. Now I had to unfortunately, modify 1 of the core file `slick.grid.js` with the following code:

```
//-- slick.grid.js --//

// on line 69 insert this code
autoExpandColumns: false,

// on line 1614 PREVIOUS CODE
if (options.forceFitColumns) {
    autosizeColumns();
}

// on line 1614 change to this NEW CODE
if (options.forceFitColumns || options.autoExpandColumns) {
    autosizeColumns();
}
```

then going back to my grid definition, I replace my previous options with this:

```
// My NEW SlickGrid Options
var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    forceFitColumns: false,     // make sure the force fit is false
    autoExpandColumns: true     // <-- our new property is now usable
};
```

with this new change it has some functionality of the force fit (expanding) but does not restrict you on resizing your columns width afterwards like the force fit does. I also tested it with the columnPicker, if you hide a column it's resizing the others accordingly. I also modified the file `slick.columnpicker.js` to include a checkbox for that property but that is totally optional...I can add the code for that too if any of you want it as well. Voila!!! :)

**EDIT #2**
I realized much later that there's no need to modify the core file, we can simply call `grid.autosizeColumns()` after the grid creation. Like this

```
var options = { forceFitColumns: false };
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);

// will take available space only on first load
grid.autosizeColumns();
```

This will automatically resize the columns to fit the screen on first load but will not give you the restriction of the `forceFitcolumns` flag.

Comment: Thanks - the issue I have with this is that using forceFitColumns, the  columns will grow in width if they can. I need them to stay at their set width, but the last empty column grow to fill the remaining space.

Comment: The only way I can find to do this is to initially set the min/max width the same, and then after the grid is rendered, set them to null. Also - in the window resize event, set the min/max to width again before the resizeCanvas, then null them again afterwards.

Comment: I came up with a different approach, that is working exactly like I always wanted...no more annoying width restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kind late for this reply.

But i've managed to do that without having to change things at slick.grid.js or set min/maxWidth at columns array.

Instead what i did was to iterate through the columns array adding the values of "width" field of each column and then i've did a simple math count to set the last column width as innerWidth - totalColumsWidth + lastColumnWidth.

Code:

```
function lastColumnWidth(columns)
{
        var widthSum = 0;
        angular.forEach(columns, function(col) {
            if(col.width) { widthSum = col.width + widthSum; }
        });
        if(window.innerWidth > widthSum) {
            columns[columns.length-1].width = columns[columns.length-1].width + (window.innerWidth - widthSum);
        }
        return columns;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Raphael Koszalka's idea, I combined this with the Resizer plugin.

The resizer plugin is demonstrated in [example 15](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example15-auto-resize.html).

You adjust the final column width in the onGridAfterResize hook.

```js
import { SlickResizer } from 'slickgrid';

let resizer = new SlickResizer({
   container: '.grid1enc'
});
grid.registerPlugin(resizer); 
resizer.onGridAfterResize.subscribe(resize_handler);

function resize_handler(e,args) {
   const grid=args.grid;
   const best=calc_final_column_width(grid,400);

   const columns=grid.getColumns();
   columns[columns.length - 1].width=best;
   grid.setColumns(columns); // fixes the column header
};

function sum_of_all_but_last_column_widths(columns) {
   let sum=0;
   for (let c=1; c<=columns.length - 1; c++) {
      sum=sum+columns[c-1].width;
   };
   return sum;
};

function calc_final_column_width(grid,min) {
   const mywidth = grid.getGridPosition().width;
   const sum=sum_of_all_but_last_column_widths(grid.getColumns());
   return mywidth > sum + min ? mywidth-sum : min;
};
```

Tested on 6pac Slickgrid v5.