# slickgrid resizable not refreshing rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

- I have added a container div around the slickgrid (the container has a heading etc just to make it all look neat and tidy).
- I have made the div resizable using jquery and instructed it to resize the grid and viewport simultaneously.

It works wonderfully (everything resizes in unison) but the number of visible rows does not update until I scroll.

Is there a way to force the viewport to refresh?? grid.render does not work.

```
$(".container").resizable({
    alsoResize: ".grid, .slick-viewport",
    resize: function (event, ui) { }
});

$(".container").on("resize", function (event, ui) {
    dataView.refresh();
    grid.render();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

In case anybody has the same problem, the answer is grid.resizeCanvas();

The code now looks like this:

```
    $('.container').each(function () { // I have several grids + containers
       var gridID = $(this).attr('id'); // get the container ID
       $(this).resizable({
       // for some reason, there was a problem with $(this) - I had to use
       // an explicit reference by passing the container ID
           alsoResize: '#' + gridID + ' .grid, #' + gridID + ' .slick-viewport',
           resize: function (event, ui) { }
       });

       $('.container').on('resize', function (event, ui) {
           grid.resizeCanvas()
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at an answer I gave for an auto grid resize, it's auto-resizing with the viewport and so changing the size of your browser will be reflected on the grid size... 

See it here: [Slickgrid: Final column auto size to use all remaining space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360367/slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space/17374444#17374444)