# How to have slickgrid columns of different width?

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I want my slickgrid to have different width for each column (because of my long as well as short data)...but cant get anything to work..

Using `forcefitcolumns: true` creates same width for each column.

Even `minWidth` and `maxWidth` provide different width to the column in header and other rows.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution...use `maxWidth` and `minWidth` and also apply `forcefitcolumns : true`...
In that case columns will occupy remaining space with different widths

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at an answer I posted on a previous question asked, which seems very similar to your problem... see here [slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360367/slickgrid-final-column-auto-size-to-use-all-remaining-space/17374444#17374444)

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

You can give width in columns Array as follows:

```
var columns = [
    { 
       id: "Id", 
       name: "ColumnName", 
       field: "fieldName", 
       width: 100, 
       cssClass: "cell-title", 
       validator: decimalFieldValidator 
    }
];
```